# Tetgen expression -d unexpected output

Tags: python, graphics, subprocess, tetgen

I am trying to clean some meshes with the help of tetgen. Starting tetgen with **python** subprocess and saving my output in a file like this

```
run(["tetgen", "-d", Model+"\\Cat\\Cat.ply"], stdout= log_output, encoding="utf-8")
```

I get this result:*"For convenience I will enter only interested parties"*

```
Warning:  Point #53491 is coincident with #25597. Ignored!
Warning:  A segment and a facet intersect.
  segment: [669,668] tag(-1).
  facet triangle: [28562,28564,28563] tag(-1)
Warning:  A duplicated triangle (24976,52879,52863) tag(-1) is ignored.
...
```

However this is not what I want, because to clean this mesh I have to eliminate some triangles that are "duplicates" and to extrapolate them I have this **regex**:

```
\((\d+),\s(\d+),\s(\d+)\) and \((\d+),\s(\d+),\s(\d+)\)
```

Looking online I noticed that the output for tetgen's **"-d"** expression is as follows:
Detecting intersecting facets.

```
  Facet #5672 intersects facet #5730 at triangles:
    (2872, 2874, 2873) and (2834, 2873, 2833)
  Facet #5726 intersects facet #5750 at triangles:
    (2872, 2873, 2834) and (2868, 2874, 2872)
  Facet #5730 intersects facet #5750 at triangles:
    (2834, 2873, 2833) and (2868, 2874, 2872)
```

Which would lead to matches with the regex I have available, which doesn't happen with the output I currently get.

**QUESTION:**
*Ultimately I was wondering if anyone was aware of the reason for this difference in output information given by the expression "-d" and if eventually he could tell me what I'm doing wrong! Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the tetGen version from 1.6.0 to 1.5.1.